# MySQL strange behavior with comma separated list of numbers

Tags: mysql, implicit-conversion

I had a very complicated problem, but i narrowed it down to this,  First, let me give you some test data:

Run this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES
(1),
('1'),
('1,2'),
('3');
```

Now run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE value = 1;
```

I would expect in this case to get only the first two rows, where the value is either entered as a numeric 1 or a '1' char, but for some reason this is what i get:

```
1, 1
2, 1
3, 1,2
```

My question is, why do i get the third row?

Note: This is my version of mysql: 5.6.28-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

Also, I already solved my original problem by using FIND_IN_SET and I am aware that it's not a very good idea to have this comma separated list type structure, ie, it should probably have been done with a join table in the first place.  Unfortunately I'm working within a system that is very large and making that change is not practical at this time.

I'm just interested in why this specific behavior happens.

Comment: Can we instead reject the premise of the question? Don't start with a comma separated list of numbers.

Comment: @Strawberry: Regardless of whether it's a good idea to store comma separated lists of numbers, it's a good question.  The behavior is unexpected.

Comment: Have you tried InnoDb table format same behaviour?

Comment: There seems to be something going around with implicit type conversion. Try `value = '1'` instead.

Comment: @Whome Same thing with InnoDb

Comment: @KamilG. This does fix the problem, but doesn't explain why i had it in the first place

Comment: Kudos to OP to narrowing down a complex problem to a specific question. +10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you get the third row is *implicit datatype conversion* performed by MySQL. Your query has a predicate (condition) in the WHERE clause

```
  WHERE value = 1
```

On the right side of the equality comparison operator (the equal sign), we have a *numeric literal*. On the left side, we have a column that is datatype TEXT.

It's not possible for MySQL to do a comparison of those two different datatypes.

So, MySQL converts one side or the other to a type that is compatible, so a comparison can be performed.  In this case, MySQL is converting the value from the column to be *numeric*, so it compare to the *numeric* literal.

As a demonstration of what that looks like, we can add a zero (forcing MySQL to do a conversion), and exhibit the results in a SELECT.

```
 SELECT t.value, t.value + 0 FROM test t

 t.value  t.value + 0
 -------  -----------
 1                  1
 1                  1
 1,2                1
 3                  3
```

It's documented in the MySQL Reference Manual somewhere, how MySQL does the conversion. At a risk of misstating what the manual says: MySQL reads the string character by character from left to right, until it encounters a character where it can no longer convert to numeric.

In the case if the string `'1,2'`, that happens to be the comma character. That's where MySQL stops. So the conversion returns a numeric value of 1. You would be right to point out that other databases would throw an error attempting to do a conversion of that string to numeric. But MySQL doesn't throw an error or warning.

Reference: [**Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html)

Basically, the predicate in your query is equivalent to specifying:

```
   WHERE value + 0 = 1
```

Which forces a conversion of the contents of the column `value` to numeric, and then a comparison to the numeric literal.

That's why the third row is being returned.

To get a different result, consider comparing to a *string literal*

```
   WHERE value = '1'
```

Comment: _Note for future readers_: Postgres would throw an error saying _operator does not exist: text = integer_.

Comment: @MikeNakis - there are reasons why people implemented that type conversion. Your comments are not constructive, and you are not even aware of MySQL strict mode. I won't get into a discussion here, but these comments "it's good enough reason to switch to X" makes you look like a beginner. Please, for the sake of everyone who are reading this and for yourself, don't do that. It's so annoying to read these "I will jump to a conclusion now without any knowledge" comments, it really helps NO ONE.

Comment: @MikeNakis - ok, mind doing it for yourself then and avoid influencing others with your invalid logic? I thought you appeared as a beginner, but it looks like you are one.

Comment: @MikeNakis - some people live on this planet, reading quotes and thoughts of other people without ever having one of their own - and that happens for a reason. I'm done here, I've no intention on having yet another argument with yet another "me too" person. If you're as thick as you appear to be, then I'm better off having a serious debate with a pencil.

Comment: @MikeNakis It's worth noting that MySQL is not alone in this. PHP and Javascript also do it when you use a string in a numeric context.